# AttributeError in Python when attempting to initialize a class in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to call a class into a class's initializing method, but I am receiving an attribute error. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be occurring? I was able to do this exact thing with another class, but it doesn't seem to like the `Movement()` class I made.

The `add_piece()` method in `Board()` seems to be the one causing the issues.

```
class Movement:
    """
    Class to help separate movements from the board methods
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ind(self, pos):
        """
        Converts the string input to an easier index for the board
        """
        row = int(pos[1:]) - 1
        column = self.letter_to_column(pos)
        return row, column

    def letter_to_column(self, pos):
        """
        Method to convert string letters of columns to int to index
        """
        column_dict = {}
        column_dict['a'] = 0
        column_dict['b'] = 1
        column_dict['c'] = 2
        column_dict['d'] = 3
        column_dict['e'] = 4
        column_dict['f'] = 5
        column_dict['g'] = 6
        column_dict['h'] = 7
        column_dict['i'] = 8
        return column_dict[pos[0]]

# BOARD -------------------------------------------------------------------
class Board:
    """
    Represents the board and its pieces
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Builds the board and places the pieces in its spots
        """
        self._board = []
        for i in range(10):
            self._board.append([None for i in range(9)])
        self.place_pieces()

        self._move = Movement()

    def add_piece(self, pos, piece):
        """
        pos is a string of a letter (column) and a number (row)
        for example pos = 'a2' which is the first column in the second row
        """
        self._board[self._move.ind(pos)[0]][self._move.ind(pos)[1]] = piece
```

Comment: you're calling `place_pieces()` instead of `add_pieces()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't related to `Movement`: it's related to a missing method in `Board`. `Board.place_pieces` is not defined, so the expression `self.place_pieces()` in `Board.__init__` will throw an `AttributeError`.

As an aside—if the only purpose of the `Movement` class is to collect related helper functions, you might want to consider making those `classmethod`s or `staticmethod`s instead ([which you can read more about here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)):

```py
class Movement:
    COLUMNS = {
        letter: index
        for index, letter in enumerate("ABCDEFGH")
    }

    @classmethod
    def get_indices(cls, coordinate):  # cls is to class methods what self is to instance methods.
        # Rough validation of the coordinate:
        if not len(coordinate) == 2: 
            ...  # Raise some exception.

        # Assignment via sequence unpacking
        # See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences
        column, string_row = coordinate.upper()
 
        # Row should be representable as a digit and 
        # in a specific range.
        row_index = int(string_row)
        if row_index < 1 or row_index > 8:
            ... # Raise an exception.

        # If column isn't in ABCDEFGH, the dictionary
        # access here will throw (desirable).
        return row_index - 1, cls.COLUMNS[column]
```

`Movement.COLUMNS` is a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) generated using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a built-in function that we use to return an index for each letter in the string `ABCDEFG`.

You can then skip the creation of `self._mode` and write:

```
row_index, column_index = Movement.get_indices("A2")
```

in `Board.add_piece`, for example.